# How can i give a where condition before update_batch in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I want to update my table where the input the same input fields names are array and has 
add more function which generates the input fields like this:

I want to do update_batch in codeigniter
my model i created a function like this:
This is the code block:

```
    function update_batch_all($tblname,$data=array(),$userid)
    {
       $this->db->trans_start();
       $this->db->where('userid',$userid);
       $this->db->update_batch($tblname,$data);
       $this->db->trans_complete();
       return TRUE;
    }
```

it is not working.
can any one help me that how can i update tables data with update batch that has where condition?

Answer (score 1):

You can read the docs for `update_batch()` [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#update)

Here's the short summary:

You pass in an associative array that has both, your where key, and the update value. As the third parameter to the `update_batch()` call, you specify which key in your assoc array should be used for the where clause.

For example:

```
$data = array(
  array(
    'user_id' => 1,
    'name' => 'Foo'
  ), array(
    'user_id' => 2,
    'name' => 'Bar'
  )
);

$this->db->update_batch($tbl, $data, 'user_id');
```

**Breakdown of arguments passed**:`$tbl` is the table name. `$data` is the associative array. `'user_id'` tells CI that the `user_id` key in $data is the where clause.

**Effect of the above query:** Name for user with `user_id = 1` gets set to `Foo` and name for user with `user_id=2` gets set to `Bar`.

In your case, if you want to set the same `user_id` key in each array with your `data` array, you can do a quick for loop:

```
foreach ($data as &$d) { 
  $d['user_id'] = $user_id;
}


$this->db->update_batch($tbl, $data, 'user_id');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use,

      $this->db->update_batch($tblname,$data,'user_id');
```

But all array within data must have a field 'user_id'

eg:

```
    $data=array( 

               array('user_name'=>'test1','user_id'=>1),
               array('user_name'=>'test2','user_id'=>2)

                  );
```

You can get more details about update_batch from [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)